# Displaying entries from a specific custom date year

Tags: entries, datetime, custom

I've a list of entries, all with custom dates. 
Is there a way to show entries from a specific year, just using the custom date rather than the posted date?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Are "custom dates" dates from a Date/Time custom field on the entries?

Comment: They are - sorry, should have been a bit clearer.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using this code.

```
{% set upcoming = craft.entries.section('section').order('customDate')%}            

{% for entry in upcoming %} 
    {% if entry.customDate =='2018-10-12' %}    
        {{entry.title}}         
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Works for now anyway.

Comment: if you want a specific year not just a specific day of the year you can do something like this `entry.customDate|date('Y') == '2018'`.